# `Error: file is not a database` in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

I have created a database named `database.db`.

When I create a table in the database, I get the error `Error: file is not a database` as shown below:

```
nehal@nehal-Inspiron-5559:~/Desktop/UAV$ sqlite3 database.db 
SQLite version 3.20.1 2017-08-24 16:21:36
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE users(
   ...> password varchar(10),
   ...> email text,
   ...> name text
   ...> );
Error: file is not a database
```

**How do I resolve the error?**

Comment: How did you try to create it?

Comment: What do you mean? @CL.

Comment: You said "I have create a database".

Comment: sqlite3 database.db

Comment: I ran into this when I created the db with `sqlite` but then used `sqlite3` on another system.  i.e. perhaps you are mixing versions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create database without the `.db` extension.

for e.g. `sqlite3 users   //this creates a database names users`

Comment: can you provide the reference how you came to this solution? Thanks

Comment: @PratikMistry I guess this answer is wrong. I observe the "file is not a database" error occurs when you `sqltile3` with an old `sqlite` file ...

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan ok, will try to see if that's the case in my case as well.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the db to sqlite3?

Comment: I believe this answer is creating a new database file `users` instead of opening `users.db` or `database.db`, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

The error can occur when a database was created with cipher.
So `sqlite3_open` succeded but any `sqlite3_exec` or `sqlite3_prepare` will be failed with this error.

Comment: can you elaborate on this a bit more? I am working with cipher and get I this.

Comment: After `sqlite_open` you should provide cipher params. How to do it is depended on your cipher library. I use [SQLite3 Multiple Ciphers](https://utelle.github.io/SQLite3MultipleCiphers/) and this library has both `C` and `SQL-pragma` APIs. So I run several sql statement via `sqlie3_exec` like `pragma <cipher-param>=<cipher-value>` and then work with database as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

**.open users**

it will also create the database

and to open an existing database users.db use

**.open users.db**

if .db is not used new database of same name will be created

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with WPF and SQLiteAdministrator creating a SQLite v3 DB with Database->New->SQLite 3 DB option and "Data Source=whatever.s3db; Version=3" in the WPF code using System.Data.SQLite library.

Select Database->Migrate to SQLite3 option in SQLiteAdministrator solves the problem. Its works for me. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> Error: file is not a database

Because I exported `apple.db` to `backup.sql` with `.dump` or `.schema` as shown below. *`.dump` can export schema with data and `.schema` can export only schema:

```
sqlite3 apple.db .dump > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 apple.db .schema > backup.sql
```

Then, I accessed `backup.sql` and tried to show the tables and schema with `.table` or `.schema` respectively as shown below:

```
sqlite3 backup.sql
...
sqlite> .table
Error: file is not a database
```

Or:

```
sqlite3 backup.sql
...
sqlite> .schema
Error: file is not a database
```

Actually, as the error suggests, `backup.sql` is not a database so it is impossible to show the tables and their schemas with `.table` or `.schema` respectively.