# sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database when creating a table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pycharm

So I'm trying to create a database that will have a table which will store user IDs, usernames, and password hashes and am using PyCharm for this project. I'm a beginner and don't know much about using PyCharm and this seems to be one of the things I know almost nothing about. Here's the code:

```
    import sqlite3

    conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")

    db = conn.cursor()

    sql = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' 
                ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                'username' TEXT NOT NULL, 'hash' TEXT NOT NULL)'''

    db.execute(sql)
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/*****/sqlite.py", line 8, in <module>
      db.execute(sql)
  sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure no preexisting file is there and delete it, just in case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974135/sqlite-error-file-is-not-a-database

Comment: I've googled the error message but I think this is specific to how PyCharm does its database connections. There's no preexisting file; I've checked.

Comment: hey I think it worked thnx for the link

Answer (score 1):

So sorry just had to create the db in the sqlite3 terminal (if you know what I mean) sorry for wasting your time.

[Sqlite Error: file is not a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974135/sqlite-error-file-is-not-a-database)